# Update button text on click rendered using map method in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am rendering some data from array of object which contains button. I am appending button text from state which is set initially as **"Select"**. What I want is when I click on any button then its value should get update as **"Selected**". Currently all button values are getting update when I click on any button.

```
const TestPage = () =>{
    let buttons = [
        {name:'Select1', id:1}, 
        {name:'Select2', id:2}, 
        {name:'Select3', id:3}
    ]
    
    const [btnText, setbtnText] = useState('Select')

    const handleClick = () =>{
        setbtnText('Selected')
    }
    return(
        <div>
            {!!buttons && buttons.map(item =>{
                return(
                    <p key={item.id}>
                        <Button btnType='button' btnText={btnText} clickHandler={handleClick} />
                    </p>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default TestPage;
```

Comment: You must give 'id' to each Button element to identify them uniquely. Pass that id to Handler method. Use that id to identify the element and then updated the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each button needs to have its own state. When you share one variable between multiple buttons, all will change if any handler changes the single variable.

```js
const Example = () => {
  const [buttons, setButtons] = React.useState([
    {name: "Select", id: 1}, 
    {name: "Select", id: 2}, 
    {name: "Select", id: 3},
  ]);

  const handleButtonClick = i => {
    setButtons(prevState => {
      const nextState = prevState.map(btn => ({
        ...btn, name: "Select"
      }));
      nextState[i].name = "Selected";
      return nextState;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {buttons.map(({name, id}, i) => 
        <button
          key={id}
          onClick={() => handleButtonClick(i)}
       >
         {name}
       </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<Example />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Another approach is to pass the `id` to the click handler and use `const i = buttons.findIndex(btn => btn.id === id)` to determine which button's name should be changed.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you also tell that if I click on other button then rest othe button text should show default text i.e. Select. Only last clicked button should show Selected text.

Comment: Does the update help? It's hard to tell if `name: "Selected1"` etc are real names or not, and whether they should be restored to `"Select1"`, `"Select2"`, etc, or just say `"Select"`. I assumed the latter. If that's a bad assumption, it might help to show a more representative snippet of your actual structure and describe the behavior a bit more clearly.

Comment: Yes. its latter one. Default name would be same. And yes your updated answer worked for me. Thanks again for your help.